# Syntax Procedure Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in phpmyadmin but when I try to create a second one, I get the error

> #1327 - Undeclared variable.

This works fine:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE id_pro INT(9);
    SELECT user_product_id INTO id_pro FROM usuario;
END
```

But if I want to add another variable, I get the error above:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE id_pro INT(9);
    DECLARE date_product datetime;
    SELECT user_product_id INTO id_pro, date_pro INTO date_product FROM usuario;
END
```

It doesn't detect `date_product` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign `INTO` several variables, use the following syntax:

```
SELECT user_product_id, date_pro INTO id_pro, date_product FROM usuario;
```

See [the MySQL `SELECT ... INTO` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html).

Answer (score 0):

Or don't use `INTO`:

```
SELECT id_pro := user_product_id, date_product := date_pro 
FROM usuario;
```